# How to set config for gitlab?

Tags: git, version-control, config, gitlab

I used the [official guide](https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README) to the configuration. The key is generated. Don't understand how to set config.
Here is my file:

```
[core]
  repositoryformatversion = 0
  filemode = true
  bare = false
  logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
  url = https://gitlab.com/kas-elvirov/notepad.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ssh key](https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README) has nothing to do with an https url.

- https would use your GitLab account credential.
- ssh would use `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)`

If you want to use the ssh url, you should at least switch to ssh with:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.com:akas-elvirov/notepad.git
```